# Error 1064 DB_driver después de instalar Community Auth

Tags: mysql, mariadb, codeigniter-3

Después de instalar la librería e intentando hacer las primeras pruebas, me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'WHERE `id` = 'pas2nc4ee1atc5kotg9l01m1b59hamhf'' at line 2
>
> SELECT `data` WHERE `id` = 'pas2nc4ee1atc5kotg9l01m1b59hamhf'
>
> Filename: C:/.../system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

El error se encontraría en el script DB_driver (Codeigniter 3.3.1)

¿Posibles causas del error?¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar? Gracias

Comment: Me llama la atención que el error provenga de  DB_driver, ya q es un script del framework, Ya agrego la sentencia

Comment: Linea 691: `return $this->display_error(array('Error Number: '.$error['code'], $error['message'], $sql));` En la línea 2 no hay código, sólo documentación del script

Comment: Hola Gaby, ¿Podrías agregar el código donde haces la consulta?. También te dice que es en la linea dos pero de las instrucciones sql que se están enviando, no que en tu código de php en la linea 2 está el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te marca error de sintaxis porque no se está especificando la tabla en la cual se va a realizar la búsqueda.
Esta es tu consulta

```
SELECT data WHERE id = 'pas2nc4ee1atc5kotg9l01m1b59hamhf'
```

Debería de ser algo así

```
SELECT data FROM miTabla WHERE id = 'pas2nc4ee1atc5kotg9l01m1b59hamhf'
```

Comment: Entiendo. Pasa que como no es código propio, me sorprende el error,ya que proviene de la librería y no del código previo a su instalación. Quizás tenga que configurar algo?

Comment: opté por borrar y volver a reinstalar y no tuve problemas. Había sido un error mío en la instalación. Gracias por tu tiempo. Saludos